# Is it possible to browse a maven repository on Artifact Registry as a guest?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

Typically one can browse public Maven repositories

So I was wondering if the same is available for a maven repository create on Artifact Registry

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Public Access to a repository as described in the following article: [Configuring public access to a repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#public).

> To configure a repository for public read-only access, grant the Artifact Registry Reader role to the member `allUsers`.

Comment: I'd like to have the possibility to browse it in case, like [this](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/). With such address (`artifactregistry://europe-west6-maven.pkg.dev/galvanized-case-306920/kx`) doesn't seem possible..

Comment: It doesn't look like it's possible wit the Artifact registry, however, you can create a [Feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so it could be considered for the future releases.